# Running Selenium with ChromeDrive in .NET Core Docker container

Tags: docker, selenium, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to get running a Chrome Driver within a .NET Core within a Docker container. Is this possible?

I got this error message + stacktrace:

```
Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:34893/
    at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions 
options, TimeSpan commandTimeout) 
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options)
```

My code:

```
    // fileName is the chromedriver file
    var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(folderName, fileName);
    var webDriver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

The docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 6002
    ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:6002

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY . .
    RUN dotnet restore "ASPNETCORE.csproj"
    WORKDIR "/src/ASPNETCORE"
    RUN dotnet build "ASPNETCORE.csproj" -c Release -o /app

    FROM build AS publish
    WORKDIR "/src/ASPNETCORE"
    RUN dotnet publish "ASPNETCORE.csproj" -c Release -o /app

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app .  
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ASPNETCORE.dll", "--server.urls", "http://*:6002"]
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: add your dockerfile please

Comment: added it to the question